# Error in geom_col() : could not find function "geom_col"

Tags: ggplot2

Estoy intentando hacer un trabajo y me aparece el siguiente error:

> Error in geom_col() : could not find function "geom_col"

Además, tengo la siguiente versión:

> packageVersion("ggplot2") [1] ‘3.3.6’

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error para poder aplicar **geom_col()**?
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

en primer lugar te recomendaría añadir el código entero ya que lo que te ocurre allí es que estás ejecutando geom_col como si fuese una función y es una capa de ggplot, por lo tanto tienes que poner delante la función ggplot con el + y las coordenadas necesarias para dar como resultado la gráfica qaue necesitas. Si quieres, edita la pregunta con el código y te puedo indicar mejor donde está el fallo